# Angular provider not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning Services in Angular. T tried service and factory and could get them working , but I am not able to get provider working. I checked out the solutions of few SO answers too, still couldn't get it to work

This is my provider:

```
app.provider('EmployeeService', function EmployeeServiceProvider() {
    var list = [{
        name: '',
        skill: ''
    }];

    this.$get = function() {
        return {
            getList: function() {
                return list
            },
            add: function(employee) {
                list.push(employee);
            }
        };
    }
})
```

And my controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, EmployeeService) {

    $scope.employee = {
        name: '',
        skill: ''
    };
    $scope.employees = EmployeeService.getList();
    $scope.add = function(employee) {
        EmployeeService.add(employee);
        $scope.employee = {
            name: '',
            skill: ''
        }
    }
});
```

And app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.config(['EmployeeServiceProvider', function(EmployeeServiceProvider) {
    var user = {
        name: 'Rob',
        skill: 'Hacker'
    };
    EmployeeServiceProvider.add(user);

}]);
```

My html is this:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AngularJS app</title>
    <script src="js\angular\angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app\app.js"></script>
    <script src="app\controllers\MainCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="app\services\EmployeeService.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller='MainCtrl'>
        <input type="text" ng-model="employee.name" placeholder="Enter employee name"/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="employee.skill" placeholder="Enter employee skill"/>
        <button ng-click="add(employee)">Add</button>
        <hr>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Skill</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="person in employees">
                    <td>{{person.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{person.skill}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am expecting to add the values in the config before providing it in the HTML. But I am not able to do it. Nothing shows up in the console as well. Kindly let me know how to correctly configure the provider and use it in config.

Comment: Do you necessarily need this to be a provider (i.e., do you need it at the module configuration phase) or are you simply using a provider because you couldn't get a factory or service to work?  From what I can tell, this would make better use as a factory/service.

Comment: I am actually learning Angular Services. I learnt factory and services without any issues. But I can't seem to make providers work.

Comment: You should `return` and object which has the `$get` property instead of setting `this.$get`, so, for example, in your provider:  `return { getList: function() { }, $get: function() { } };`

Comment: I actually followed this tutorial - http://tylermcginnis.com/angularjs-factory-vs-service-vs-provider/ . Do you mean to say that I should have $get inside the return ? What should be inside $get then ?

Comment: Your question is almost there; but you need to define what you mean by 'doesn't work'? Do you receive console errors when you run this code? If so, what are they? When you're debugging it, what happens? Is something undefined that you expect not to be? What is it?

Comment: @ViChU: Yes, you should have `$get` inside the `return`. and inside $get, you should return the functions used by your controller(namely, `getList` and `add`)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I have added my problem statement. Sorry for not stating it beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in your `provider` code. Your provider needs to return an object containing `$get` property. Simply adding `$get` to `this` wont work. inside `$get`, you need to return the functions beings used by your controller(namely `add()` and `getList()`)

*You need to keep the `add` function at two places:*

**First, right within the provider's `return{ }`(as a sibling to `$get`)** because you are using it in `config` function.

```
app.config(['EmployeeServiceProvider', function(EmployeeServiceProvider) {
    var user = {
        name: 'Rob',
        skill: 'Hacker'
    };

    EmployeeServiceProvider.add(user);   //<--  Here

}]);
```

**Second, you need to keep the add function within `$get`'s return** since you are using it in your controller.

```
$scope.add = function(employee) {
    EmployeeService.add(employee);   <-- Here
    $scope.employee = {
        name: '',
        skill: ''
    }
}
```

Here's the complete code for your provider:

```
app.provider('EmployeeService', function EmployeeServiceProvider() {
    var list = [{
        name: '',
        skill: ''
    }];

  return{
    add: function(employee) {    //This is for Config's visibility
        list.push(employee);
    },    
    $get:function(){
        return{
            add: function(employee) {    // This is for controller's visibility
                list.push(employee);
            },    
            getList: function() {
                return list
            }          
        }
    }

  }
})
```

You can also bind the methods(`$get` and `add`)  to `this` instead of returning a separate object

```
app.provider('EmployeeService', function EmployeeServiceProvider() {
    var list = [{
        name: '',
        skill: ''
    }];

    this.add= function(employee) {
        list.push(employee);
    }
    this.$get = function() {
        return {
            getList: function() {
                return list
            },
            add: function(employee) {
                list.push(employee);
            }
        };
    }  

})
```

And here's the working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bGqHMZKNFxy4wOcNeq5i?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Actually I followed a tutorial -  http://tylermcginnis.com/angularjs-factory-vs-service-vs-provider . So is it wrong in that tutorial ?

Comment: @ViChU: No, that tutorial is not wrong, but you would need to bind an `add` function with `this` to make it visible for `app.config`. Have a  look at this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KLi5gXn6VhA2Z5aaXB1p?p=preview)

Comment: @ViChU: Updated the answer. Please check :)